# Liquidity pool without UI from Raydium

Tags: spl-token, solana-cli, liquiditypool

I'm looking to create a SPL token and I'm wondering if you can create a liqudity pool / remove liquidity pool without using the UI on Raydium.

Answer (score 0):

you can reference these link for implemention.

https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/blob/master/src/ammCreatePool.ts

https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/blob/master/src/ammRemoveLiquidity.ts

this includes demonstrations of utilizing Raydium SDK.

Comment: I am creating a pool using this code. I am stuck on the `feeDestinationId` parameter. What address should I use for this if I create the pool with a random SPLtoken on the Devnet?

Comment: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-amm/blob/master/program/src/processor.rs


devnet: 3XMrhbv989VxAMi3DErLV9eJht1pHppW5LbKxe9fkEFR

mainnet: 7YttLkHDoNj9wyDur5pM1ejNaAvT9X4eqaYcHQqtj2G5